# How to Dockerizing a Angular 2 web app via node js?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I tried out finding many ways for Dockerizing angular 2 web app using node js but not yet worked it is running on local but not working on docker container.Does anyone have any proper **Dockerfile** and **package.json** file for docking angular 2 app.

[image]

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5655
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

Site cant be reached while accessing

Below are some possible ways i found on stack over flow but not worked

```
docker run --rm --name my-container -it -p 8080:4200 -v $(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

in package.json even i kept my port as dynamic `"ng serve -host 0.0.0.0",`

And also suggest me which server i need to use either **nginx** or **node** for docking angular 2 web-app

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'"
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Your angular app must be served by any type of http servers - it can be a simple node.js file with configured "express" module inside. Can you post here the content of your package.json or at least the "scripts" section from it?

Comment: @sergiy.dragunov 

  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'"
  },

Comment: @sergiy.dragunov i have added my script above description section

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all I would suggest to run "npm start" at your machine;
2. and check if after this you can reach you angular app in a browser;
3. if this works - you will need to remember at which port your angular app is served;
4. add new RUN section "RUN npm run build:prod" right before EXPOSE line;
5. set correct port at section EXPOSE;
6. run you container: "docker run --rm --name my-container -it ."
7. open browser at http:127.0.0.1:HERE_PORT_FROM_EXPOSE_SECTION

Here is a small example:
https://github.com/karlkori/dockerized-angular-app

Also I want to add that for production it will be better to use Nginx or CloudFront.

Comment: sergiy.dragunov Same error not worked with above steps

Comment: is your application private? can you share it code on github or bitbucket?

Comment: added a link to example